# Prism. Навигация. Не срабатывает OnNavigatedFrom

Tags: wpf, mvvm, навигация, prism

Здравствуйте!
Один из классов реализует интерфейс [`INavigationAware`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware(v=pandp.50).aspx), соответственно срабатывает метод [`OnNavigatedFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware.onnavigatedfrom(v=pandp.50).aspx) перед деактивацией view, т.е. когда происходит запрос навигации:

```
 _regionManager.RequestNavigate("RegionName", new Uri("viewName", UriKind.Relative))
```

Но когда я делаю деактивацию "вручную":

```
foreach (var page in _regionManager.Regions["RegionName"].Views)
{
    _regionManager.Regions["RegionName"].Deactivate(page);
}
```

вьюха деактивируется, но метод `OnNavigatedFrom` не срабатывает.

Кто-нибудь знает с чем это связано?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, достаточно посмотреть исходники призма. Буду отвечать по четвертой версии, ибо ей пользуюсь.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Marks the specified view as inactive. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="view">The view to deactivate.</param>
    public virtual void Deactivate(object view)
    {
        ItemMetadata itemMetadata = this.GetItemMetadataOrThrow(view);

        if (itemMetadata.IsActive)
        {
            itemMetadata.IsActive = false;
        }
    }
```

Это всё, что делает Deactivate.
Чтобы вызвать OnNavigatedFrom, надо вызвать OnNavigatedTo, как ни странно.

Посмотрим в код RegionNavigationService:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes", Justification = "Exception is marshalled to callback")]
    private void ExecuteNavigation(NavigationContext navigationContext, object[] activeViews, Action<NavigationResult> navigationCallback)
    {
        try
        {
            // Вызовем OnNavigatedFrom для всех зарегистрированных в регионе вьюх
            NotifyActiveViewsNavigatingFrom(navigationContext, activeViews);

            object view = this.regionNavigationContentLoader.LoadContent(this.Region, navigationContext);

            // Raise the navigating event just before activing the view.
            this.RaiseNavigating(navigationContext);

            this.Region.Activate(view);

            // Update the navigation journal before notifying others of navigaton
            IRegionNavigationJournalEntry journalEntry = this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<IRegionNavigationJournalEntry>();
            journalEntry.Uri = navigationContext.Uri;
            journalEntry.Parameters = navigationContext.Parameters;
            this.journal.RecordNavigation(journalEntry);
             // Вызовем OnNavigatedTo для новой вьюхи
            // The view can be informed of navigation
            InvokeOnNavigationAwareElement(view, (n) => n.OnNavigatedTo(navigationContext));

            navigationCallback(new NavigationResult(navigationContext, true));

            // Raise the navigated event when navigation is completed.
            this.RaiseNavigated(navigationContext);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.NotifyNavigationFailed(navigationContext, navigationCallback, e);
        }
    }
```

Надеюсь, теперь поведение очевидно.